# how to move a group to next page JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to JasperReport and I have the below question:

I want to finish page after group. For example:
There are two groups in my report group and subgroup. I prepared a report and I want, if my subgroup will move to other page, it can move with group.
[image]

I don't want my subgroup dont move other page, if it is gonna move other page, my group can move other page with my subgroup.

Comment: Share a [MCVE], otherwise it will be difficult for anybody!

Comment: ^^ share some jrxml, there are different ways to do this logical <break>, minHeightToStartNewPage, and splitType='prevent' but with no jrxml its hard to tell which one is most suitable

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
its link my report: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-fVQxfjtqwFaVlQdEVJbGtZbTA/view?usp=sharing my subreport: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-fVQxfjtqwFZ2h4VzUwMkNSbzA/view?usp=sharing

thanks petter fribery but i couldnt find settings that you was talking about.

Comment: Ok I can't see any **groups**... I see detail band with a supreport in it, I guess you like to move the data in detail band to next page i subreport overflow... this is done by setting splitType="prevent" on the detail band in main report, now you have "stretch"

Comment: Please next time instead of adding additional info in comment, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35198557/edit) your post, consider to move content in comment and delete the comment... If you still have troubles you can ping the people in chat putting @ before the name...

Comment: its done now and im so happy :)) i m new on this site thank you for everything @PetterFriberg :)

Comment: You like to do a favor to the community, check if to accept the duplicate (it basically same stuff, want subreport with text on same page.... If you agree check "accept duplicate"

Comment: my English is bad i tried to understand you and do something, i hope i did @PetterFriberg

Comment: You did well, thanks and welcome to SO!, remember for your next question if you have troubles try to create a [mcve] in jasper report the jrxml code is very important....